# Using ContentManager.Create to add new ContentTypes from a Service within Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

Let's say I have a ContentType defined in the Migrations.cs

```
public int Create(){
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("UserWrapper", builder => 
builder
.WithPart(typeof(UserPart).Name)
.WithPart(typeof(CommonPart).Name)
.Creatable();
return 1;
}
```

I then have a service that will be called from a controller after a person "sign-ups" for example (like a user signup page), and this method "CreateUserWrapper" uses ContentManager to create a new UserWrapper (code is below):

```
public void CreateUserWrapper(string email){
var userWrapper = orchardServices.ContentManager.New("UserWrapper");
var userPart = userWrapper.As<UserPart>();
userPart.Email = email;
userPart.UserName = email;
userPart.NormalizedUserName = email.ToLowerInvariant();
userPart.Record.HashAlgorithm = "SHA1";
userPart.Record.RegistrationStatus = UserStatus.Approved;
userPart.Record.EmailStatus = UserStatus.Approved;

orchardServices.ContentManager.Create(userWrapper);

}
```

The above code does not add a new user. When I go to the "users" section of the admin dashboard there isn't a new user. Also, there isn't a new contentType of UserWrapper added. Where am I going wrong, why doesn't this code call back through to NHibernate and update the Db?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the above code works. Here's the deal, I actually felt that my VS2010 was kinda buggy, so I reinstalled the SP1 and after running this exact same piece of code again it works. You can totally update ContentTypes from ContentManager.Create in the way described above.